# Is c an integer or a float in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

In the book "Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Gilbert Strang, the author says the linear combination is cv + dw. I know that v and w are vectors. But are `c` and `d` continuous variables? i.e. can c or d be 1.1 or 1.2 etc?

Comment: The scalars depend on the field the vector space is defined over. For fields of characteristic zero the rationals will be a subfield but for finite fields this isn't the case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Comment: Be careful with your language: "float" would typically refer to floating point arithmetic, which has some additional baggage coming from its application in computing.  That said, typically an introductory linear algebra textbook, if the base field is not specified, is just talking about the real numbers.  In context, $c,d$ could be any real numbers (more akin to floats than integers), but more generally they would be any elements of the base field.

Comment: Thanks! I meant real number.